# The value for the promptBeforeIdle property must be less than the timeout property

Tags: reactjs, idle-timer

I'm using the `react-idle-timer` library to prompt users on idle.
This is how I have integrated it.

```
  const eventsTimer = useIdleTimer({
    element: document,
    startOnMount: false,
    startManually: true,
    name: "events-timer",
    onAction: createPageEvent,
    events: ["click", "mousemove", "keydown", "touchstart", "change", "select", "scroll"],
  });

  // USER ACTIVITY TIMER
  const activityTimer = useIdleTimer({
    crossTab: true,
    syncTimers: 200,
    startOnMount: false,
    startManually: true,
    name: "activity-timer",
    timeout: expireTestTime * 60 * 1000, // in miliseconds
    onIdle: () => sendMsgToBackground({ action: ACTION.USER_ACTIVITY_IDLE }),
  });
```

It was working fine earlier but recently when I did the `npm i` to install the required libraries, it stopped working. Now I'm getting the error like **The value for the promptBeforeIdle property must be less than the timeout property idletimer**.

I'm not using the `promptBeforeIdle` property but still I'm getting this error. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Just faced a similar issue. promptBeforeIdle is 0 by default. So check to confirm that your timeout is never 0 at any point. promptBeforeIdle must always be less than timeout

Comment: First of all, I'm not even using both of these properties. 
Second, I have also tried doing that but still it gives me the same message.
By the way, I was working perfectly fine in v5.4.2. This issue is only occurring in the latest version.